# How to handle multi-region writes for a joint user registration?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, asynchronous-programming, distributed-system, data-replication

UserA and UserB are signing up for some joint service together. They both have to independently agree to T&Cs before sign-up is complete. Once complete they both receive an email to sign-in.

A 1 or 0 is being stored in a MySQL table (TC_ACCEPTANCE) to indicate T&C agreement for each user (USER_A_ACCEPTED and USER_B_ACCEPTED). After writing ‘1’ for a user, I  read back the same row to see if the other user has accepted. If they have, an email is sent.

However I also need to consider the multi-region scenario, where these users may be in different regions and therefore have different data stores.

I’m thinking of handling this by duplicating the TC_ACCEPTANCE table in both regions. e.g. UserA accepts, set ‘1’ for USER_A_ACCEPTED in RegionA, commit the transaction, then call RegionB to set ‘1’ for USER_A_ACCEPTED in RegionB.

I’m also thinking of making this write to RegionB synchronous before returning a success response to UserA. UserA will experience additional latency but I’m honestly not familiar with doing an async guaranteed delivery and worry if I’d be overcomplicating things by doing so.

**Do I overall have a reasonable approach here? Also can someone point me in the right direction to explore implementing the async approach?**

Comment: Can you please share more details about your current architecture? By reading, I thought you had the same data stores' structures in multiple regions. But then you said "replicating TC_ACCEPTANCE" in both regions. Don't you already have this table in both regions? Also, if you can tolerate a little latency in one of the users, why not putting this  registration in only one region, to make things simpler? I'm not sure if this is the best too, I guess we need some more details on your problem.

Comment: @EmersonCardoso Sorry for the confusion. Yes the table is in both regions but I'm questioning if it's the right thing to do. The reason why I don't handle this in only one region is because the registration has a dozen steps preceding the T&C acceptance that each user has to go through that's only relevant to said user. This preceding info goes into a REGISTRATION_INFO table and has a FK reference to TC_ACCEPTANCE.